# Cannot read property reduceof undefined from mongo

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, properties, reduce, use-effect

Good evening,
I have an issue with my code :

```
import React, {useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import ReactApexChart from 'react-apexcharts';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import {fetchCountries} from "../../actions/countries.actions"

function ChartActualAchi() {

  //Fetching data : 
  const countries = useSelector((state) => state.countriesReducer)

  const [loadCountries, setCountries] = useState(true)
  const dispatch  = useDispatch()

      useEffect(() => {
          if(loadCountries) {
              dispatch(fetchCountries())
              setCountries(false)
          }
      }, [loadCountries])

const Actual = countries
.reduce((a,c) => 
(c.phase === "actual" && c.year === 2020 ? a + c.amount : a),0)


  // ApexChart part : 
  const series = [Actual];

  const options = {
         chart: {
           height: 350,
           type: 'radialBar',
         },
         plotOptions: {
           radialBar: {
             hollow: {
               size: '70%',
             }
           },
         },
         labels: ['Actual vs Budget'],
       };

  return (
    <div>
      <ReactApexChart
        options={options}
        series={series} 
        type="radialBar" height={250} />
    </div>
  )
}

export default ChartActualAchi
```

When I export the const 'Actual' in the const 'series' I have this error message : cannot read property reduce of undefined.
What I am missing because the data is loading from the store.
I tried to do this :

```
const Actual = countries && countries
.reduce((a,c) => 
(c.phase === "actual" && c.year === 2020 ? a + c.amount : a),0)
```

but it's not working either.

Hope this is clear enough.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Whats the error msg for second approach `countries && countries
.reduce` ?

Comment: Maybe `const countries = useSelector((state) => state.countriesReducer.countries) `

Comment: @wrangler : I've got a message error : "Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'type' of undefined". Ajeet Shah : I have this : "TypeError: Cannot read property 'countries' of undefined"

Comment: You need to make sure that `countries` is an array of some elements (or empty array `[]` when data isn't loaded from API).

Comment: Write a `console.log(countries)` after `const countries = useSelector((state) => state.countriesReducer)`. And tell us what is logged.

Comment: It tells "undefined". I don't understand because Redux dev tools is loading data.

Comment: You are loading `countries` through an API call. So, is it always `undefined`, or first it is `undefined` but later takes the array data after API call succeeds?

Comment: It's always undefined.

Comment: In that case, you need to debug why it is always undefined. Is it getting saved properly in Redux store after API call succeeds? Are you passing correct function inside `useSelector`?

Comment: I resolved it by correcting the reducer and the store. Thanks for the tips !